# How to translate such AS3 class into C#?

Tags: c#, flash, actionscript, events, translation

So I try to create opensource C# project for slicing FLVs I began with translating of existing project called [flvslicer](http://code.google.com/p/flvslicer/)

Can any one please help me with translating one of their classes

```
package org.bytearray.video.events
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public final class MergedEvent extends Event
    {
        public var time:Number;
        public var stream:ByteArray;

        public static const COMPLETE:String = "mergeComplete";

        public function MergedEvent(type:String, stream:ByteArray, duration:Number)
        {
            super(type, false, false); // base
            this.stream = stream;
            this.time = duration;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't C# you're going to have a long and hard road ahead of you, you really should read up on some C# tutorials and learn a bit about the language and .NET before you start this project.

Comment: Tip: You are doing it wrong, first, it's a Event class, in c#, there's a difference way to make events. Also, just look at the code and try to do it in c#, do not translate it.

Comment: Seems like *give the codez* request. What have you tried so far to tackle this problem?

Comment: Walk before you run. *Crawl before you walk.*

Comment: I dont think it will be as easy as just translating to c#, for instances the class above extends Event, inhertitance is available in c# but what is Event? i assume that the base class Event exposes the Stream and time fields set in the MergedEvent constructor?

Comment: no - event - default AS3 class.

Comment: ok seen the declarations now, missed them initially

Comment: After reading that '=)' smile, I need to say this to you: You'll fail hard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# you have two separate items, an `EventHandler<TArgs>` declaration and the custom `EventArgs` subclass.

```
public event EventHandler<MergedEventArgs> MergeComplete;

public class MergedEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public double Time { get; set; }
    public byte[] Stream { get; set;
}
```

Comment: And if I wanted to add a function to my Event as public override function toString ():String
  { 
   return "[MergdEvent duration="+time+"]"; 
  } 
what shall I do?

Comment: And how to create something like 'this.time = end - start;'

Comment: @Ole Jak, you really should pick up some books and tutorials on C# and just work through those.  http://www.amazon.com/Learning-C-3-0-Jesse-Liberty/dp/0596521065